# How can i enable artisan commands in cpanel?

Tags: laravel-5, phpstorm, cpanel, laravel-artisan

as you probably knew when we connect to C Panel and host by remote in php storm ...

we are not able to use from php artisan commands

how can i enable it? in really host?

Comment: i tried   artisan::call(config:cache) in my route but it doesn't work

Comment: If I got you right and you want to run Artisan as a PhpStorm command-line tool remotely, this approach is not yet supported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23740